# Engineers : only 3 bridges

Tags: terra-mystica

Are the engineers limited to only 3 bridges?

I ask this just as confirmation. I can't find this anywhere in the rules, but I suppose it's so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are still limited to 3. Though the rulebook does not seems to mention this specifically in regards to engineers, it says:

> Keep in mind that you can only build a total of three Bridges.

And nothing in the section about engineers says otherwise.